# Call class method while instantiating?

Tags: c#

I don't know how to describe it better so the title might be a bit confusing.

I would like to know if it is possible to instantiate a class by using `... = new MyClass()` and to call non static methods of this class instantly while instantiating?

For example something like that:

```
return new MyClass().SetName("some name");
```

I guess I have seen something similar like this before but I can't find it.
It is a bit annoying to do something like...

```
MyClass myclass = new MyClass();
myclass.SetName("some name");
return myclass;
```

Is there a way to shorten it or to do it like my first example?
(Please do not suggest me to use a property instead of `SetName(string)` - it is just an example)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your example would attempt to return the result of `SetName` which would (I assume) be `void`.

Comment: If your example isn't a good example - changing `Name` to be a property seems entirely reasonable - then you should change your example to be a *good* one.

Comment: As stated above use a property. Then you can call a constructor with parameters like: `new MyClass { Name = "myName" }`

Comment: If the methods should *always* be called, they should be in the constructor. If they should only *usually* (but not always) be called, you should have two constructors (or one constructor with a parameter which defines what to do). If they are not usually called, then I assume you wouldn't be asking this question in the first place.

Comment: Alternately, you could add a constructor that took the name as a parameter MyClass(String name), and then set the name variable (or property) there.

Comment: Search for the Builder / "fluent" pattern. (That said, it's arguably overkill for objects where the builder method calls don't traverse a state chart. If all you want to do is call a bunch of methods in sequence on the same object, I wouldn't bother.)

Comment: Last but not least it's easier to set breakpoints in separate statements for debugging porpoises.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well, if you *did* have a property, you could use an object initializer:

```
return new MyClass { Name = "some name" };
```

If you really, really have to use a method, then the only option is to make the method return the instance again:

```
public Foo SomeMethod()
{
    // Do some work
    return this;
}
```

This you can write:

```
return new Foo().SomeMethod();
```

As a really *extreme* way of doing things if you can't change the methods you're calling, you could write an extension method:

```
public static T ExecuteAndReturn<T>(this T target, Action<T> action)
{
    action(target);
    return target;
}
```

Then you could write:

```
return new Foo().ExecuteAndReturn(f => f.SomeMethod());
```

But that's really foul. It would be *far* simpler to use a local variable in these cases...

Comment: The strange thing is that the pure fact that Jon Skeet did not mention the (otherwise seemingly straightforward and harmless) solution I proposed (constructor argument) makes me feel there is something seriously wrong with it. This is twisted!

Comment: @ppeterka: Well I'm assuming that the OP wants to do something which *can't* be done with a constructor argument. It's hard to know from the bad example though.

Comment: Oh, Ok. This explains it. I stepped back from the ledge, and the firemen are still not here, so I think I can get away with it...

Answer (score 7):

If `SetName` returns `this`, then you can do exactly what you wanted to do in your first code example.

Comment: Resisting the downvote is very difficult here. It's a bad solution and obscures intent, violating serps.

Comment: If you imagine revisiting such code in the future, it is not possible to determine what is going on simply by looking in one place. In order to establish the intent of the code, a layer of indirection exists that clouds one's ability to understand the code. At least with the original 3 lines, the intent is immediately obvious.

Comment: I didn't try to argue for or against such a design. In my opinion fluent interfaces are often less useful than many people think. I was just simply answering the OP's question while abandoning any moral or ethical discussion.

Comment: Indeed... I suppose it's more of a statement to OP than to you.

Answer (score 7):

There is a **huge misconception** in the question:

> ...and to call non static methods of this class instantly while instantiating
>
> For example something like that:

```
return new MyClass().SetName("some name");
```

The truth is that calling the `SetName` function *happens after* the instantiation is finished. It is not happening "while instantiating". This is exactly the same as:

```
MyClass newInstance new MyClass();
return newInstance.setName("some name");
```

So by the time the `SetName` method is called, the constructor has finished everything it needs to do, the object is ready on the heap.

Apart from this, it is syntactically doable, you just have to return `this` as others have noted, and of course specify the return type accordingly. I wouldn't do this for setters however... This is just not nice.

Also, if you always have to set the name, consider having a constructor expecting the name as an argument, and set it in the constructor:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public String name;
    public MyClass(String initialName)
    {
        name = initialName;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it in a really short form:

```
MyClass instance = new MyClass("someName");
```

Answer (score 6):

That's easily done. Typically this is called a "fluent interface", but with more appropriate method names.

Here's how you would write SetName to function like that:

```
public MyClass SetName(...)
{
    ...
    return this;
}
```

This will allow you exactly the syntax you wanted.

You can then chain multiple such calls, typically to different methods:

```
return new MyClass().SetName("kkk").SetAge(44).SetAddres("...");
```

However, I would suggest you also consider adding a more appropriate construct that does all this.

Comment: Note that a "fluent interface" is generally not used in this context though.  Fluent interfaces are generally applied to *immutable* objects, not *mutable* objects.

Comment: Well, specifically they are usually used on mutable builder objects that are passed to the constructor of an immutable object.

Answer (score 3):

You can make the methods chainable like this:

```
public void SetName(String name) {
    this._name = name;
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Unless `SetName` is of type of the class that hosts it and returns `this`, there is no way that you could avoid an intermediate variable. Of course you can adopt a fluent syntax, and make your `SetName` return the object, but that is not a native idiom to C#.

```
class MyClass {
    public int A {get;private set;}
    public int B {get;private set;}
    public MyClass SetA(int a) {
        A = a;
        return this;
    }
    public MyClass SetB(int b) {
        B = b;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
return new MyClass().SetA(123).SetB(456);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a static property that will act as a factory, returning a new instance. In that case a call would look like:

```
MyClass.GetInstance.SetName("some name");
```

Not sure if this is what you want. Alternatively, why don't you call that method from within a constructor and pass the needed params through the constructor.

OR, third option, build a factory class that will handle all these extra steps and return to you an instance.